# Banshee play queue won't add songs and switches to play library

Tags: music, banshee

(This might not be the most appropriate place to ask these questions, but I can't find any relevant information on my problem anywhere and the primary mean of communicating among Banshee-users is a mailing list ...)

I use Banshee 2.6.2 on Ubuntu 13.10 and have encountered two, possibly unrelated, problems with the Play Queue extension.

The play queue has a function (called »Auto DJ«) where you select a play list and set it up so the queue is filled (by album, track, year or whatever) randomly and automatically. However, the queue is not filled properly - it adds an album but then stops. Clicking »Add more« only works intermittently, possibly only when a few songs remain in the queue.

The second problem arises when the queue reaches the end of it's Auto DJ-added content (an album, in my case). Instead of carrying on playing which I would expect it to (since there are another album, added by clicking »Add more«), it starts playing from the library!

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: The second problem could be argued as a feature, though I could see why you might want it configurable. The first is something I find frustrating also. I've given up using the DJ and added stuff manually. I guess if I want random play, I switch to pandora. I wish I could use banshee for it though